# WebGL mixes colors on pixel level

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, shader, webgl

I want to write a small program that calculates for example prime numbers. My idea was to use webgl/threejs to color all pixels that represent prime numbers (based on coordinates) white and the rest black. My problem is that webgl somehow mixes the colors on pixel level (if you have a white pixel in the middle of a black canvas it mixes with the environment and the pixels around that one white pixel become gray). With this problem, I can't identify white and black pixels properly.

My Question: How can I tell webgl or canvas to use the correct color for each pixel without mixing things?

Here is a demo where I colored every 2nd pixel white:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ProjectLaGPU</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform float u_start;

        varying float v_start;

        void main() {
            v_start = u_start;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying float v_start;

        void main () {
            if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==0 && int(gl_FragCoord.y)%2==0) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
/* main.js */
async function init() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-.5, .5, .5, -.5, -1, 1);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
        powerPreference: "high-performance",
        depth: false,
        stencil: false
    });

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            u_start: { value: 0.5 },
        },
        vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertex-shader").innerText,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragment-shader").innerText,
      });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    renderer.setSize(1000, 1000);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    scene.add(mesh)
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previously accepted answer is not correct and only worked via luck... In other words if it worked for you you were lucky that your machine/browser/OS/current-settings happened to appear to work. Change a setting, switch to another browser/os/machine and it will not work.

There are many issues being conflated here

### 1. Getting non-blurry canvas

There 2 things you have to do to get a non-blurry canvas

#### turn off the browser's filtering

In Chrome/Edge/Safari you can do this with `canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }` on firefox `canvas { image-rendering: crisp-edges; }`

Note that `pixelated` is more correct for this situation than `crisp-edges`. From the spec, given this original image

[image: original-image]

And displaying it 3x the size the default algorithm is up to the browser but a typical example might look something like this

[image]

`pixelated` would look something like this

[image: pixelated-style]

**IMPORTANT: See update at bottom**
`crisp-edges` would look something like this

[image: crisp-edges-style]

But note that the actual algorithm used to draw the image is not defined by the spec  so at the moment firefox happens to use nearest-neighbor filtering for `crisp-edges` and does not support `pixelated`. Therefore you should specify `pixelated` last so it overrides `crisp-edges` if it exists

A canvas has 2 sizes. Its drawingbuffer size (the number of pixels in the canvas) and it's display size (defined by CSS). But CSS sizes are computed in CSS pixels which are then scaled by the current `devicePixelRatio`. This means if you're not zoomed in or out and your on a device with a `devicePixelRatio` that's not 1.0 and your drawingbuffer size matches your display size then the canvas will be scaled to what it needs to be to match the `devicePixelRatio`. So, the `image-rendering` CSS style will be used to decide how that scaling happens.

Example

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-.5, .5, .5, -.5, -1, 1);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertex-shader").innerText,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragment-shader").innerText,
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(mesh)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
canvas { 
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;  /* pixelated is more correct so put that last */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        void main () {
            if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==0 && int(gl_FragCoord.y)%2==0) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
</script>
```

#### turn off antialiasing.

Three.js does this for you

### 2. Getting 1 pixel in the canvas = to 1 pixel on the screen

This is what calling `setPixelRatio` was trying to do. That it appeared to work for you was just luck. In other words when you try to run your code on a different machine or different browser it may not work.

The issue is in order to set the size of the canvas's drawing buffer so that it matches 1 to 1 how many pixels will be used to display the canvas you have to ask the browser "how many pixels did you use".

The reason is for example, let's say you have a device with device pixel ratio (dpr) of 3. Let's say the window is 100 device pixels wide. That's 33.3333 CSS pixels wide. If you look at `window.innerWidth` ([which you should never do anyway](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html)) it will report 33 CSS pixels. If you then multiply by your dpr of 3 you get 99 but in reality the browser may/will draw 100.

To ask what size was actually used you have to use [`ResizeObserver`](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/#dom-resizeobserverboxoptions-device-pixel-content-box) and have it report the exact size used via `devicePixelContentBoxSize`

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-.5, .5, .5, -.5, -1, 1);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertex-shader").innerText,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragment-shader").innerText,
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

function onResize(entries) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    let width;
    let height;
    let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
    if (entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize) {
      // NOTE: Only this path gives the correct answer
      // The other 2 paths are an imperfect fallback
      // for browsers that don't provide anyway to do this
      width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
      height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
      dpr = 1; // it's already in width and height
    } else if (entry.contentBoxSize) {
      if (entry.contentBoxSize[0]) {
        width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
        height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
      } else {
        width = entry.contentBoxSize.inlineSize;
        height = entry.contentBoxSize.blockSize;
      }
    } else {
      width = entry.contentRect.width;
      height = entry.contentRect.height;
    }
    // IMPORTANT! You must pass false here otherwise three.js
    // will mess up the CSS!
    renderer.setSize(Math.round(width * dpr), Math.round(height * dpr), false);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}

const canvas = renderer.domElement;
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(onResize);
try {
  // because some browers don't support this yet
  resizeObserver.observe(canvas, {box: 'device-pixel-content-box'});
} catch (e) {
  resizeObserver.observe(canvas, {box: 'content-box'});
}
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(mesh)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        void main () {
            if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==0 && int(gl_FragCoord.y)%2==0) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Any other method will only work sometimes.

To prove it here's the method from using setPixelRatio and window.innerWidth vs using ResizeObserver

```js
function test(parent, fn) {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-.5, .5, .5, -.5, -1, 1);
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertex-shader").innerText,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragment-shader").innerText,
  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  fn(renderer, scene, camera);
  parent.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  scene.add(mesh)
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resizeOberserverInit(renderer, scene, camera) {
  function onResize(entries) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      let width;
      let height;
      let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
      if (entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize) {
      // NOTE: Only this path gives the correct answer
      // The other 2 paths are an imperfect fallback
      // for browsers that don't provide anyway to do this
        width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
        height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
        dpr = 1; // it's already in width and height
      } else if (entry.contentBoxSize) {
        if (entry.contentBoxSize[0]) {
          width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
          height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
        } else {
          width = entry.contentBoxSize.inlineSize;
          height = entry.contentBoxSize.blockSize;
        }
      } else {
        width = entry.contentRect.width;
        height = entry.contentRect.height;
      }
      // IMPORTANT! You must pass false here otherwise three.js
      // will mess up the CSS!
      renderer.setSize(Math.round(width * dpr), Math.round(height * dpr), false);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  }

  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(onResize);
  try {
    // because some browers don't support this yet
    resizeObserver.observe(canvas, {box: 'device-pixel-content-box'});
  } catch (e) {
    resizeObserver.observe(canvas, {box: 'content-box'});
  }
}

function innerWidthDPRInit(renderer, scene, camera) {
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.deivcePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 70);
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.deivcePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 70);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
}

test(document.querySelector('#innerWidth-dpr'), innerWidthDPRInit);
test(document.querySelector('#resizeObserver'), resizeOberserverInit);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
}
#resizeObserver,
#resizeObserver>canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        void main () {
            if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==0 && int(gl_FragCoord.y)%2==0) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
</script>
<div>via window.innerWidth and setPixelRatio</div>
<div id="innerWidth-dpr"></div>
<div>via ResizeObserver</div>
<div id="resizeObserver"></div>
```

Try zooming in the browser or try different devices.

## Update

[The spec changed in Feb 2021](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6038). `crisp-edges` now means "use nearest neighbor" and `pixelated` means "keep it looking pixelated" which can be translated as "if you want to then do something better than nearest neighbor that keeps the image pixelated". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596405/128511)

Comment: You might want to add an `else if (entry.contentBoxSize) {` clause, current FF doesn't pass it as sequence yet, but it does have it anyway.

Comment: Is it different from `contentRect`? Is `contentRect` going away?

Comment: On my FF the values do differ yes, and I see nothing saying `contentRect` would leave.

Comment: hmmm, on my tests `contentRect.width` seems to be more accurate than `contentBoxSize.inlineSize`. The later seems to be truncated.

Comment: For me they did really differ in values, but after like 5 decimals. Which is weird, since per specs they should be the same "content rect"... And actually `.contentRect` may indeed get deprecated in the future, but I hope that when browsers will do so they will also implement devicePixelContentBoxSize or at least contentBoxSize as a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical side effect for not configuring the device pixel ratio. Meaning your app does not necessarily run in a native solution. The following produces the expected result (I've made a screenshot and checked the color values in Gimp).

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-.5, .5, .5, -.5, -1, 1);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertex-shader").innerText,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragment-shader").innerText,
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(mesh)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>

<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        void main () {
            if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%2==0 && int(gl_FragCoord.y)%2==0) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: This is not correct and only worked via luck.

Comment: "I've made screenshots and checked the values" != it works. Here's your example on my machine: https://i.imgur.com/HYKczZe.png